# I write code for simple camera capture image.but application and camera not getting connected and one unhandle error is showing

Tags: c#, emgucv

I an new in emgu cv c#. I want to create a camera only for simple photocapture from my laptop camera and other camera device connected to my laptop.I dont want video capture only simple photo capture.with one start and one capture button.and will save in particular location.helped would be appreciable.

```
namespace camera
{
public partial class cameracaps : Form
{
    Capture capturecam=null;
    bool capturingprocess=false;
    Image<Bgr,Byte>imgOrg;
    Image<Gray,Byte>imgproc;



    public cameracaps()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            Capture cam = new Capture();

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            return;
        }
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(processFunction);
        capturingprocess=true;

    }
    void processFunction(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
       imgOrg=capturecam.QueryFrame();
        if(imgOrg ==null)return;
        imgproc=imgOrg.InRange(new Bgr(50,50,50),new Bgr(250,250,250));
        imgproc = imgproc.SmoothGaussian(9);
        original.Image=imgOrg;
        processed.Image=imgproc;
    }


    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(capturingprocess==true)
        {
            Application.Idle-=processFunction;
            capturingprocess = false;
            Button1.Text="play";
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Idle+= processFunction;
            capturingprocess= true;
            Button1.Text="pause";


    }


}

}
}
```

showing..The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception. error..indicating error in
                `Capture cam = new Capture();`
help me.

Comment: This question will get closed because you haven't provided anything that shows any effort. Look for more information about the subject and come back once you have a concrete issue, this is too broad.

Comment: sir ,i coded for the camera before.but didnot mentioned because unhandle error was showing please help me.

Comment: A few others and I have voted to reopen your question, you will be helped shortly. You should edit your post and specify what error you're getting.

Comment: And don't beg people to help! It will have the opposite effect.

Comment: did u unhold my questions?because am not getting any answer.from last 7 days am trying to solve this error day and night.its important for me to solve

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the biggest problem almost all the time we face in emgu cv.First of all copy dll file name opencv_core290.dll,open_cvhighgui290.dll to your project bin,try to use dependency tracker for dll files.Install dependency from this link-http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation..If its not work then you should understand that application is getting connection with camera.Then go to My computer->right click->property->advanced system setting->system property->advance->environment variables->system variables->path->edit->and paste C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922\bin.and press ok.restart your system and it will work.

Comment: Go to project property->build->change the output path->C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922\bin\..Problem solved..